# Apache site disabled still serving

Tags: apache-2.2

This is totally server fault i think. :)

I have a site that disabled in Apache but server still serving it. I tried to stop/restart the server with no success. How can i debug this?

Config:

OS: Debian

Server: Apache2

Site disabled with a2dissite, config file removed automatically from sites-enabled.

Thanks,
fabrik

Comment: How is it disabled?  What platform (Windows/Linux/?) Can you a relevant portion of your Apache config.

Comment: Did you reload the configuration?

Comment: yep, and tried with other sites too where Apache normally disabled/enabled them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, /etc/apache2/conf.d/, /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/. I think it'll be easy to find out even if you don't have much experience with apache.

Comment: no success, most of them are the defaults. site configs stored in sites-available and sites-enabled.

Comment: Remove the config file from site-enabled. I've never used a2dissite but after you remove the site, the config file should not be in site-enabled directory.

Comment: As i wrote in the opening post, config file removed automatically. When i disable any other site Apache working normally.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.
Can you find something using this command:
find . | xargs grep site_name

Comment: That's it! Absolutely no idea how but another config pointed to this domain. Thank you Gk!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I had disabled the site using a2dissite your_domain. But I also had to run a2dissite your_domain-le-ssl. Then reload apache 2.